# How to get all product information as per category Id using Rest API in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, products, rest-api

**I got product SKU as per category id with following code**

```
$requestUrl='https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/V1/categories/3/products/';
```

With the above code, I am getting all SKU for category id 3.
After getting product SKU I want to get all product details.

```
$requestUrls="https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/all/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%201VA1184%25
";
```

But above code returning nothing ....
Anyone can help me regarding this
Thank you.

```
<?php
//API URL for authentication
$apiURL="https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
//parameters passing with URL
$data = array("username" => "sarveshmobileapp", "password" => "Sarvesh@123");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($apiURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length: ".strlen($data_string)));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
//decoding generated token and saving it in a variable
$token=  json_decode($token);
//******************************************//
//Using above token into header
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ".$token);
//API URL to get all Magento 2 modules
$requestUrl='https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/V1/categories/3/products/'; ///V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20 ///V1/products?searchCriteria
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//printing result
//print_r($result);
//decoding result
$results=  json_decode($result,true);
foreach($results as $result){
    /*echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';*/
    echo $sku = $result['sku'].'<br>';
}
echo $requestUrls="https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/all/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=124-VG2303
"; ///V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20 ///V1/products?searchCriteria
$ch = curl_init($requestUrls);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resultr = curl_exec($ch);
//printing result
print_r($resultr);
```

Comment: you're passing wrong url. 
 $requestUrls="https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%201VA1184%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=visibility&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=3,4&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
$requestUrls="https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/all/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=201VA1184";
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php
//API URL for authentication
$apiURL="https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
//parameters passing with URL
$data = array("username" => "sarveshmobileapp", "password" => "Sarvesh@123");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($apiURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length: ".strlen($data_string)));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
//decoding generated token and saving it in a variable
$token=  json_decode($token);
//******************************************//
//Using above token into header
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ".$token);
//API URL to get all Magento 2 modules
$requestUrl='https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/V1/categories/3/products/'; ///V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20 ///V1/products?searchCriteria
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//printing result
//print_r($result);
//decoding result
$results=  json_decode($result,true);
foreach($results as $result){
    /*echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';*/
    $sku = $result['sku'].'<br>';
}
$requestUrls="https://www.vaibhavjewellers.com/staging/index.php/rest/all/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=201VA1184";
$ch1 = curl_init($requestUrls);
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '. $token
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch1);

//decoding result 
$r = json_decode($result, true); 

echo $r['items']['0']['name'].'<br>'; 
echo $r['items']['0']['price'].'<br>'; 

 for($i=6; $i<=8; $i++){

    echo $r['items']['0']['custom_attributes'][$i]['attribute_code'].'<br>';
    echo $r['items']['0']['custom_attributes'][$i]['value'].'<br>';
 }
```

Comment: i am getting error Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

Comment: you should use a token for that in your authentication

Comment: using `rest/V1/integration/admin/token`

Comment: i am passing token kindly check updated questions

Comment: now i want to remove all data expect name, price image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92736/discussion-between-magefms-and-sarvesh-tiwari).